# Mock a property of a string

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

What I'm trying to accomplish is to mock a the split inside a method like this

```
def method_separator(s):
    try:
        a, b, c = s.split('-')
        print a, b, c
    except: ValueError:
        print "An error occurred or so"
```

In the test

```
with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
    with mock.patch(What to put here?) as mock_patch:
    mock_patch.return_value = "TEXT" # To raise ValueError
    this = method_separator('Some-good-text') # The mock should not let this good test to pass
```

I've made the mock working with **string.split**

```
def method_separator(s):
    try:
        a, b, c = split.string(s, '-')
        print a, b, c
    except: ValueError:
        print "An error occurred or so"

with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
    with mock.patch('string.split') as mock_patch:
    mock_patch.return_value = "TEXT" # To raise ValueError
    this = method_separator('Some-good-text') # The mock should not let this good test to pass
```

Even if that work, the question remains, it is posible to do? mock the result of **"".split('-')**

Comment: Why would you need to *mock* that?! Just pass in a string that splits to the appropriate values.

Comment: That method there is just a fragment, the idea is to mock that specific part, that's why I'm putting it on a method to see how. In the main method that string comes from methods I can't manipulate.

Comment: Then you mock those methods, to return an appropriate string. Without an actually representative example, it’s hard to suggest further.

Answer (score 1):

The string you want to split is passed into your method. You don't need to use `patch`, just pass a [Mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock) into the method.

```
# Production Code
def method_separator(s):
try:
    a, b, c = s.split('-')
    print a, b, c
except: ValueError:
    print "An error occurred or so"

# Test Code
from unittest.mock import Mock

with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
    mock_string = Mock(spec=string)
    mock_string.side_effect = ValueError("Some message")
    this = method_separator(mock_string)
```

`patch` is useful when you want your production to get a mock *through an import statement*. If you pass values directly to your production code, you have to make your own Mock objects.